# Non-Embedded Webpage in Flutter

Tags: flutter, url, launcher

I have an app that uses url_launcher plugin. The Apple Appeal board said "The App opens the url in a web view inside the app, instead of linking it out of the app to open the mobile browser."

Do you know how to launch a url in Flutter that is not embedded in the app?

Comment: The url_launcher doc said "on iOS, the default behavior is to open all web URLs within the app. Everything else is redirected to the app handler."

Is there another option to open the url outside of the app?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55121

```
 _launchURL([String _url]) async {
   if (await canLaunch(_url)) {
      await launch(_url,forceWebView: false,forceSafariVC: false);
   } else {
     throw 'Could not launch $_url';
   }
 }
```

Setting the flag - forceSafariVC to false launches the url outside of the app

Comment: but it launches url still in the embeded browser :(

Answer (score 0):

It is weird, the default value is FALSE, but you MUST set the forceSafariVC variable explicitly to FALSE, if you want to open the url in Safari or some browser, instead of a webview.

It's a bug!

For more details, check this link: [url_launcher forceSafariVC set to true does not work in iOS](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55121)